# JavaScript algorithm to produce chess board 8x8 grid pattern

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a program that creates a string that represents an 8×8 grid, using newline characters to separate lines. At each position of the grid there is either a space or a “#” character. The characters should form a chess board.

Passing this string to `console.log` should show something like this:

```
 # # # #
# # # #
 # # # #
# # # #
 # # # #
# # # #
 # # # #
# # # #
```

When you have a program that generates this pattern, define a variable `size = 8` and change the program, so that it works for any size, outputting a grid of the given width and height.

```
var hash = "#";
var space = ' ';
var size = 8;

for (var x = 1; x <= size; x++); {
  var line = ' ';

  for (var y = 1; y <= size; y++); {
    if (x % 2) {
      if (y % 2) {
        line = line + space;
      } else {
        line = line + hash;
      }
    } else {
      if (y % 2) {
        line = line + hash;
      } else {
        line = line + space;
      }
    }

  }

  console.log(line);
}
```

I'm having trouble figuring out why this is not working...:(

Comment: `var line = ' ';` <- that creates an empty space at the beginning. How is it not working, what's the output or the error?

Comment: You have a trailing semi colon on your loops which means they aren't executing: `for (var x = 1; x <= size; x++);`

Comment: Yep, semi-colons were it. Thank you! Also, the space! Didn't even consider it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the semicolons at the end of your loops:

```
for (var x = 1; x <= size; x++) {
    var line = ' ';

    for (var y = 1; y <= size; y++) {
```

With the semicolons, the engine will do the following:

1. Run the stuff after 'for' inside the brackets - `i` will be 10 afterwards
2. stuff inside the curly brackets will be executed **once** afterwards

If you add a line break it becomes obvious

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++); 
{console.log(i);}
```

The curly braces are not the body of the for, but a new block.

Comment: D'oh! Thank you for the response!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you remove `;` - s in front of `for` loops, because of that your `for` loops are not properly executing logic inside brackets (code will just run **once**):

Something like this will do what you want:

```js
var size = 8;    
for (var y = 0; y < size; y++) {
    var line = ' ';

    for (var x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        line += (y + x + 1) % 2 ? ' ': '#';
    }

    console.log(line);
}
```

Comment: Can you tell the OP where he went wrong? (the extra semi-colons). This answer is not helpful otherwise.

Comment: Why should OP use a function for this? You fixed the issue, but since you're not explaining anything, the answer isn't helping OP understand the issue.

Comment: The syntax is not wrong, the _behaviour_ is not what OP expects.

Comment: Yes, looks fine now (except that chess boards are 8x8, not 16x16 :-P). Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Thank you too, yes I will look into that :D

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I figured it was syntax but I'm so new that I couldn't immediately see it.

Comment: You are welcome, also I optimized your solution, you can replace your conditions just with one if statement.